# How do I return an element of an array in Java as a double?

Tags: java, arrays, types

I keep receiving an error in the below codetelling me that the type must be an array but its returning a double for "total[agentnumber]" in the print statement. Can anyone explain this and how I might solve it in this context?

My goal: Write code where I input the number of periods, interest rates, and number of agents (where each agent's is assigned a principal equal to its agent number i.e. agent 1 receive 100, agent 2 receives 200, etc.) and print the balances of each agent. I want to do this in a loop rather than use the compound interest formula because I am trying to learn how to use Java.

Other issue: This is a bit crazily set up because I do not know how to return the results of the for loops. Where should I place "return" and what should I be returning, supposing that I am interested in ultimately printing the equivalent of agent[agentnumber].money for each of the agents.

```
public class Person{

    public double money; // initialize

    Person(double cash){
        money = cash;
    }
}
```

```
public class Bank {

    public static double bank(double rate, double periods, int agents){
        Person[] agent = new Person[agents];
        double total;

        for( int agentnumber = 0; agentnumber < agents; agentnumber++) {
           agent[agentnumber] = new Person((agentnumber+1)*100); // assign starting incomes and instantiate players

            for(int months = 0; months < periods; months++){
                agent[agentnumber].money = agent[agentnumber].money*(1.0 + rate);
                total = agent[agentnumber].money;
                System.out.println("The total balance of player " + agentnumber + " is " + total[agentnumber]);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        bank(0.05,120,3);
    }
}
```

Comment: When asking about an error, post the complete and exact error message.

Comment: Look at how you're using `total`. Look at the line of code that the error message indicates and see if everything makes sense. Look at the error message more closely.

Comment: I don't think this would compile for multiple reasons.

Comment: total is a double (i.e. a single decimal number). What is total[agentnumber] supposed to mean?

Answer (score 0):

`total` is a double, so just print `total`out instead of `total[agentnumber]`

Answer (score 0):

> I keep receiving an error in the below code telling me that the type must be an array but its returning a double for "total[agentnumber]" in the print statement. Can anyone explain this and how I might solve it in this context?

You get this error message because `total` is a double, not an array. In order to use `[]` the type must be an array. The solution is to print `total` instead of `total[agentnumber]`.

> Where should I place "return" and what should I be returning, supposing that I am interested in ultimately printing the equivalent of agent[agentnumber].money for each of the agents.

As your program is written right now, you'll get an error because you have declared that `bank()` will return a double, but you have no `return` statement in `bank()`. It's unclear why you'd want to return anything from `bank()`. You probably want to change

```
public static double bank(double rate, double periods, int agents)
```

to

```
public static void bank(double rate, double periods, int agents)
```

and then you don't need to return anything.

Answer (score 0):

> What and where should I be returning?

You seem to just want to print out the values of an array, so nothing needs returned. In that case, you could make the method have a `void` return type. It also isn't really clear why you needed the array because the local `agents` variable isn't needed by the `main` method, so if you did want the array, you should return `Person[]` instead of `double`...

You could also clean up the code like so.

```
public class Bank {

    public static Person[] bank(double rate, double periods, int agents){
        Person[] agent = new Person[agents];

        for( int agentnumber = 0; agentnumber < agents; agentnumber++) {
           Person p = new Person((agentnumber+1)*100); // assign starting incomes and instantiate players

            for(int months = 0; months < periods; months++){
                p.money = p.money*(1.0 + rate);
                System.out.printf("The total balance of player %d at month %d is %.2f\n", agentnumber, months, p.money);
            }

            agent[agentnumber] = p;
        }

        return agent;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person[] agents = bank(0.05,120,3);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had a go at rewriting your code above and ensured it compiles. There are a few best practice things I would change if this wasn't just a demonstration which I've added in comments

```
public class Bank {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bank bank = new Bank(0.05,120,3);
    }

    // For readability and simplification I would make this public and
    // move it into it's own file called Person.java 
    private class Person {
        public double money;

        Person(double cash){
            money = cash;
        }
    }

    public Bank(double rate, double periods, int numberOfAgents) {
        Person[] agent = new Person[numberOfAgents];

        // Typical java convention is to use camel case so
        // agentnumber would become agentNumber
        for( int agentnumber = 0; agentnumber < numberOfAgents; agentnumber++) {
            agent[agentnumber] = new Person((agentnumber+1)*100);

            for(int months = 0; months < periods; months++){
                agent[agentnumber].money = agent[agentnumber].money*(1.0 + rate);
            }
            System.out.println("The total balance of player " + agentnumber + " is " + agent [agentnumber].money);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, ignore the above and read this: Issues with the above:
(1) I'm trying to get the fine number for agent[agentnumber].money after 120 iterations. However, it looks like this is double-counting by adding that TO total. I.e. the last value of agent[agentnumber].money should be what I want, no?
(2) I am trying to print the final value of agent[agentnumber].money . I had thought that using 'total' would allow me to do this but it instead exhibit the behavior above. Deleting the total = total + line and replacing total in the System.out.print statement throws up an error, however...

Comment: If I understand your request correctly the answer code should now do what you want. I've moved total out of the loop and am printing the updated money property directly.